# How do I add background music to my spritekit file

Tags: xcode, audio, sprite

Could someone give me a quick easy step by step to adding background m4a music once my app has loaded. It is a sprite kit Xcode file, and the music is in m4a format. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
@import AVFoundation;

...

AVAudioPlayer * backgroundMusicPlayer;
NSError *error;
NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"song" withExtension:@"m4a"];
backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //-1 = infinite loop
[backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

and to stop simply

```
[backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
```

note: I don't use SKAction to play background music because you can't stop it when you want

Comment: I'm using this, but there is no sound coming out

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AVAudioPlayer` for this purpose:

In your .h:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and add the following to `interface`

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

In .m, initialize player with audio oath url:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                             pathForResource:@"bg_music"
                                             ofType:@"mp3"]];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

and when you need to play the audio, you can call:

```
[player play];
```

**Note:** 
"numberOfLoops" is the number of times that the sound will return to the beginning upon reaching the end.

- A value of zero means to play the sound just once.
- A value of one will result in playing the sound twice, and so on...
- Any negative number will loop indefinitely until stopped.

Keep Coding................ :)

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'             – do you know why this happens?

Comment: @LiGe: It indicates that there is no file at your specified path/even wrong path. Check the path of the resource, case sensitivity and its extension.

Comment: Well the path is correct. I instead used the appropiate line of the und answer, which fixes my problem but I can not hear any music... :/