# Why don't I hear music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background-music

So I have an app where I want to include background music. I use the following code for the music:

**.h:** (I did also add the framework)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
```

**.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"song" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [player play];
    NSLog(@"playing music");
}
```

The path for the music file is definitly correct. The app does not crash but I just do not hear any music.

By the way: the LogMessage ("playing music") appears in the debugger.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should read the `error` for further investigation, not ignoring it especially if you have an issue.

Comment: @holex, I don't get any errors. Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: of course you don't get because you just ignore it, the `error` should not be `nil`...

Comment: @holex ok so what shall I put there?

Comment: @holex I tried both solutions from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947117/how-do-i-add-background-music-to-my-spritekit-file            - both did not work, one of them has an error instead of nil

Comment: according to the class reference it is like: `–initWithContentsOfURL:error:(NSError **)outError`. (source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/avaudioplayerclassreference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:error:), therefore you need to pass the address of a pointer of an `NSError`.

Comment: Things are case sensitive, so make sure the name is really `song` and not `Song`. Second, as others suggested, use the error parameter . before the `player` initialisation, add the following line `NSError *error;`, than change the player line to use it, as follows: `player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];`, after that, add some sort of `if` statement, that if you don't have error, play the music, otherwise, print the error. you can do it by the following line who prints a human readable output `NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);`

Comment: I tried it as you said, this is the error message: `Error: (null)`                       - any more ideas?             @holex

Comment: kind of a long-shot, but have a look at my answer here and see if implementing it changes anything http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829049/avaudioplayer-play-audio-on-music-plays-on-the-sound-box-of-phone-calls/26829309#26829309

Comment: @AMI289 - my bad, I really typed `song` instead of `Song` - thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working mate.

Answer (score 0):

Add prepareToPlay method before [player play];

```
[player prepareToPlay];
```

Hope this will work...